# Pyaudio recording for multiple hours

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying to record my microphone for multiple (~12) hours at a time. I'm getting a struct error when I try to close the stream, but it only happens after a long recording.

Here's my code:

```py
import pyaudio
import wave

import sys

import keyboard


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('recording')

    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 5
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "raw_radio.wav"

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    frames = []

    flag = False
    try:
        while(not flag and sys.getsizeof(frames) < sys.maxsize * .8):
            for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
                try:
                    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
                    frames.append(data)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    flag=True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('ended recording, now saving')
        pass

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
```

And here's stdout:

```
recording
ended recording, now saving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\record_mic.py", line 54, in <module>
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 427, in writeframes
    self.writeframesraw(data)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 416, in writeframesraw
    self._ensure_header_written(len(data))
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 457, in _ensure_header_written
    self._write_header(datasize)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 474, in _write_header
    self._sampwidth * 8, b'data'))
struct.error: argument out of range
Exception ignored in: <bound method Wave_write.__del__ of <wave.Wave_write object at 0x000001CA028A5FD0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 316, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 434, in close
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 457, in _ensure_header_written
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 474, in _write_header
struct.error: argument out of range
```

I'm thinking because I have to Ctrl+C twice to get the KeyboardInput error to raise, I'm doing something that misedits the frames list.

Comment: you don't write it in loop but you try save all data (12h of data) at the end. It can be every big data and it can make problem. I would rather write inside `while` loop and only close it when Ctrl+C is pressed. And inside loop from time to time I would create new file to split data in smaller files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to write a wave file that is longer than the wave format can represent in one WAVE chunk.

(I am not sure if a RIFF file is permitted to contain more than one WAVE chunk nor whether support for RIFF files with more than one WAVE chunk is permitted. But the wave module can read them. It just can't write them. If this were so then, there would be no actual limit to the length of a wave file.)

You are attempting to write at once 2*44100*2*(12*3600)==7620480000 or 7.3GB.

The code where the exception occurs is:

```
        self._file.write(struct.pack('<L4s4sLHHLLHH4s',
            36 + self._datalength, b'WAVE', b'fmt ', 16,
            WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, self._nchannels, self._framerate,
            self._nchannels * self._framerate * self._sampwidth,
            self._nchannels * self._sampwidth,
            self._sampwidth * 8, b'data'))
```

This writes the wave chunk header. The first L is the length of the data plus the header which limits the data to 4294967259 bytes. This is 4GB - 36 bytes

Write your file in chunks to separate files.